# What's the issue with following smarty for loop code?

Tags: for-loop, smarty, fatal-error, smarty2

I'm using smarty template engine **version 2.6.18** for my web site. I've following code for printing 1 to 4 numbers. But I'm getting error as:

```
Fatal error: Smarty error: [in view-item-request.tpl line 67]: syntax error: unrecognized tag 'for'
```

My code is as follows:

```
{for $foo = 1 to 40} 
  <p>{$foo}</p>
{/for}
```

Can someone please help me in resolving this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you using such an ancient (2007!) version of Smarty?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The {for} loop is a Smarty 3 supported syntax. For Smarty 2, you can use {section}, and use iteration instead of index to view the values as 1-40 instead of 0-39.

```
{section name=foo loop=40} 
    <p>{$smarty.section.foo.iteration}</p>
{/section}
```

Answer (score 2):

Smarty has it's own syntax. There is no `for` loop but`foreach` and `section`.

You can achieve what you want using section this way:

```
{section name=foo  start=1 loop= 40} 
  <p>{$smarty.section.foo.index}</p>
{/section}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It was exactly I was looking for. Can you please add to your answer the code to achieve same thing using for loop. It would be something new and will increase my knowledge. Can you please?

Comment: @user2839497 In this case you cannot use foreach loop. If you wanted, you should first create in PHP array with values, then assign it to PHP and then run foreach loop as in Manual

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I'm still facing one issue. Using your code I'm able to print the values from 1 to 39 only. Actually I want to print from 1 to 40. For this I tried loop <= 40 but it gave me error. How to resolve this and print numbers till 40? Can you please help me?

Comment: @user2839497 Simple change 40 to 41

Comment: Actually I'm having one variable as $total_pages and I'm using this variable as loop counter instead of 40. I'm sending this variable from PHP file. The value this variable contains is from some calculation so I can't add 1 to this figure as it wouldn't be nice practice of coding. Can you just give me some trick to include the limit number too while parsing through the loop?

Comment: `{assign var="total_pages" value=$total_pages+1}` before loop

Comment: Yes I know the way you said above but can't we do some trick with the code written in section loop?

Comment: @user2839497 There are many ways but you need to read documentation first. You can use for example `loop= $total_pages+1`

Comment: I tried with loop= $total_pages+1 but it gave me fatal error.